# Button won't open when I click on it

Tags: html

I am trying to create a sign up button however when I have to click on the button multiple times for it to open up the sign up form. How can I make it open straightaway with one click?
below is my code:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"   style="width:auto;">Sign Up</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"     class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="container">
<img src="logo.png" width="175px" height="85">
  <h1><center>Sign up with us!</center></h1>
  <p>Please fill in this form to become a member.</p>
  <hr>
  <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"     required>

  <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"  style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
  </label>

  <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"  class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, try to set modal display to none. So, the modal by default is not shows until you click the button.

```
.modal{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: I added it and it is still the same, this is my modal:                                                    .modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: #958b99;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

Comment: I think the problem is comes from your browser, try to clear your browser cache or try other browser.

Check this https://codepen.io/galihanggara68/pen/MBeVrL 
It runs as expected.